# Selecting multiple rows in jqGrid tree

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Is there any way to select multiple rows in a jqGrid tree structure? On single clicking on any row I am providing an inline editing facility and on double clicking I am expanding the row.

If I select rows with the shift key held it should select the rows. I am specifying `multiselect: true`, but it's not working.

```
rowNum:10,
rowList:[10,20,30],
pager: '#pcolch',
sortname: 'no',
treeGridModel:'adjacency',
autowidth:false,
sortorder: 'desc',
caption:"<a href='#'>Projects</a> > Tasks",
toolbar:[true,"top"],
treeGrid: true,
cellEdit: true,
sortable: true,
shrinkToFit :true, 
//viewrecords: true, 
height:'auto',
ExpandColumn:'name',
cellsubmit : 'clientArray',
multiselect:true,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of [limitations](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:treegrid#cautions_and_limitations) of the current implementation of Tree Greed seems be not full in the documentation. If you examine the source code of jqGrid you will fine [the lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.1/js/grid.treegrid.js#L132-136) which reset some other jqGrid parameters:

```
multiselect = false;
subGrid = false;
altRows = false;
pgbuttons = false;
pginput = false;
gridview = true;
rowNum = 10000; // if rowTotal is null
rowList = [];
```

So the current implementation of the Tree Grid **don't support selecting of the multiple rows**.

If you really need such feature you have to implement it yourself. To do this you can add in `colModel` the column having the [predefined](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#predefined_format_types) 'checkbox' formatter having `formatoptions: {disabled: false}` as additional option and implement the behavior of selection which you need. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5819136/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7210627/315935) for details. It could be needed to implement some additional actions in the [beforeSelectRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events) callback.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is still of interest, but today I implemented the multiselect option (Click/Ctrl-Click/Shift-Click) in a treegrid by setting the aria-selected attribute (true/false) and adding/removing the ui-state-highlight class for visual effects.

This all happens in the beforeRowSelect callback which returns false to prevent normal row selection callback.

Hope this can help someone else! I program like a 5-year-old, so please go easy on me! :-)

Last note: The variable lastSelIdx is a global variable storing the last select row index and needs to be declared outside the function.

```
beforeSelectRow: function(id, e) {
        var row = $("#" + id);
        var currSelIdx = $("#tree").getInd(id) - 1;
        if (e.ctrlKey) {
                // Ctrl was pressed - Add to selection or remove
                if (row.attr("aria-selected") == "true") {
                        row.removeClass("ui-state-highlight").attr("aria-selected", "false");
                } else {
                        row.addClass("ui-state-highlight").attr("aria-selected", "true");
                }
                lastSelIdx = currSelIdx;
        } else if (e.shiftKey) {
                // Shift was pressed. Select all between last selected and curently selected
                var rows = $(".jqgrow");
                // Select all rows between the last selected
                if (!lastSelIdx) lastSelIdx = 0;
                if (lastSelIdx > currSelIdx) {
                        selmin = currSelIdx;
                        selmax = lastSelIdx;
                } else {
                        selmin = lastSelIdx;
                        selmax = currSelIdx;                        
                }
                for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                        if (i >= selmin && i <= selmax) {
                                $(rows[i]).addClass("ui-state-highlight").attr("aria-selected", "true");                                
                        } else {
                                $(rows[i]).removeClass("ui-state-highlight").attr("aria-selected", "false");                                
                        }
                }
        } else {
                // Simple click
                $("tr[aria-selected=true]").each(function() {
                        $(this).removeClass("ui-state-highlight").attr("aria-selected", "false");
                });
                row.addClass("ui-state-highlight").attr("aria-selected", "true");
                lastSelIdx = currSelIdx;
        }
        return false;
},
```