# in jqgrid treegrid, how can i specify that i want the data collapsed by default (even though all data is loaded)

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, treegrid

I am loading a full treegrid but i would like to have it collapse to only show level 1 (versus showing everything expanded)

is there anyway to specify initial view (collapsed or expanded) when my jqgrid treegrid loads and reloads

again, i DO want to load everything to the client, but just show things collapsed as the inital view.

i don't see any option on the [main documentation page](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3atreegrid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't included in the question neither jqGrid definition nor the test JSON or XML data which you use to fill the three grid. I suppose, that you filled the 'expanded' column of the tree grid with `true`. The hidden column 'expanded' exist in the tree grid for both mode [Nested Set Model](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anested_set_model) and [Adjacency Model](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aadjacency_model). If you would set `false` in the column the tree will be not expended. See [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AdjacencyTree.htm) an example.

You should take a look in the next-to-last column of the [AdjacencyTree.json](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AdjacencyTree.json). It contains `false`, so no tree node will be expanded. The contain of the hidden columns from the JSON file are the following

```
level parent isLeaf expanded loaded
-----------------------------------
  0          false    false   true
  1     1    false    false   true
  2     2     true    false   true
  2     2    false    false   true
  3     4     true    false   true
  2     2     true    false   true
  1     1    false    false   true
  2     7    false    false   true
  3     8     true    false   true
  3     8     true    false   true
  2     7     true    false   true
```

Comment: makes sense . . i thought i had that set to false but it was true . .

Comment: I have expanded:true and loaded:true, the data loads and displays okay but i am not able to see the collapse action, as by default all the rows have been expanded. Any help?

Comment: @Shah: You should better open new question and include in the question the JavaScript code which you use and the JSON data, so one could reproduce your problem.