# Jqgrid subgrid nested levels with out headers

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am looking for an example for jqgrid subgrid with nested levels (4-5 levels) and can we display all the nested subgrids with out any headers and also by sharing the top level headers? Also is it possible to load all the subgrid data when the page is loaded...

Comment: Is it not default behavior of jqGrid (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:adjacency_model#what_we_post))?

Comment: Oleg: I have modified the question. Could you please help me in giving an example for subgrid with multiple nested levels. I have a data that I need to display in heirarchical fashion but data in db is not in heirarchical order. Also just wondering if it is possible to load and expand the subgrid data when the parent grid is loaded. If you have any demo could you please send me the link. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describes is practically the same what TreeGrid do. If it's needed you can change the default icons used by TreeGrid using [treeIcons](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:treegrid#options) option.

In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7332627/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5333199/315935) are described how to load all the data of tree grid at once.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is that I do not have my data in heirarchical order in the database, so that's why I thought I would use subgrid to get top level rows, on expansion next level and so on. Is it not possible for subgrid to hide column headers and align all subgrid data with top level headers? Any suggestions please??

Comment: @varaprakash: You are welcome! It is not important in which form the data will be hold in the database you can fill the information needed for the tree grid in any way. Almost everything is possible. The question is only how simple is the implementation. I think the problem of your question is that you try to ask it too general. Probably if you include good test data which represent the problem then all will be much more clear.

Comment: Oleg: posted a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434304/jqgrid-treegrid-for-flat-structure-data). Please take a look. Please let me know if you have any suggestions. Thanks...