# Jqgrid tree grid - displaying radio off icon for last child node

Tags: jqgrid

I am loading data for child nodes from server side on expanding the row. I wanted to display the 'ui-icon-radio-off' icon for children at the last level, currently it is displaying downward triangle as I set loaded: true, expanded: true. Is it possible to change this icon to 'ui-icon-radio-off' as shown in the attachment below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that the problem is *the data* which you used to fill the tree grid. The data should include the values of hidden columns. The column `isLeaf` defines whether the row is a tree node or a leaf. The rows which has `isLeaf: true` will be displayed with 'ui-icon-radio-off' icon.

You can find more details and example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6782262/315935), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7332627/315935), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6527790/315935) or for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6509041/315935).

Comment: Thank you Oleg. I have already defined isLeaf property in my Java bean and set the value to true but I guess it is coming as leaf: true instead of isLeaf: true, I just changed the setter method and it is coming properly now. Thanks again...

Comment: [Oleg](http://stackoverflow.com/users/315935/oleg): Could you please check my question on [grouping row data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200621/jqgrid-grouping-row-level-data)