# Multiple Highlight and Merged Row Select jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have successfully merged rows together using `jqGrid`, but I can only merge the columns with ids on them. I've two questions, if it's not too much to ask.

Current working code: http://jsfiddle.net/5B2Wh/38/

Here's the merger function that I used:

```
function Merger(gridName, CellName) {

                var mya = $("#" + gridName + "").getDataIDs();

                var length = mya.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {

                    var before = $("#" + gridName + "").jqGrid('getRowData', mya[i]);

                    var rowSpanTaxCount = 1;
                    for (j = i + 1; j <= length; j++) {

                        var end = $("#" + gridName + "").jqGrid('getRowData', mya[j]);
                        if (before[CellName] == end[CellName]) {
                            rowSpanTaxCount++;
                            $("#" + gridName + "").setCell(mya[j], CellName, '', {
                                display: 'none'
                            });
                        } else {
                            rowSpanTaxCount = 1;
                            break;
                        }
                        $("#" + CellName + "" + mya[i] + "").attr("rowspan", rowSpanTaxCount);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

**First:** 
I'd like to ask, is there a way to merge the multiple select column, such that when I check its hover over it, the merged rows will highlight also? 
In the example Fiddle, it'll look like 02-Oct-2007 will have one checkbox only on the left column.

**Second:**
*Precondition:* First question achieved and multiselect cells are merged. 
If I checked a merged checkbox in the first (leftmost) column, is there a way to bind the "Go" column's checkbox also? 
In the example Fiddle, if I checked 02-Oct-2007's merged checkbox, the checkboxes under the "Go" column within the merged cells' rowspan will also be checked, just like the sample Fiddle's current checkbox placement.

Thanks in advance for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Some time before I posted [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12294020/315935) which shows how one can use `cellattr` to do the same what you do in your demo. The usage of `cellattr` makes filling of the grid more quickly.

On the other side I don't see any simple way to implement hovering, selection and sorting behavior of such grids. So I just switched the features off.

So I have no good news for you. I still don't see any simple way to implement hovering, selection and sorting on merged cells in the column. So I can only recommend you to switch the features off.