# Adding an empty cell to the last line of jqgrid dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid

I've been working on JQGid and has a requirement to combine common cells together in one big cell as shown!

[image]

Now the requirement is the add another cell below the last to that would have a clickable button in new cell in the Address column.Which is for adding a new address for adam whose dob is 11/11/1988.

So the help I require is to create a an empty cell dynamically as the datasource for the jqgrid is a json object and I won't be able to modify the json value
PLease let me know any custom formatter you know for this specific odd requirement
Any help would be appreciated

Below given is the cellattr function I've used to combine then **Name** field

```
    cellattr: function (rowId, val, rawObject, cm, rdata) {
                    var result;

                    if (prevCellVal.value == val) {
                        result = ' style="display: none" rowspanid="' + prevCellVal.cellId + '"';
                    }
                    else {
                        var cellId = this.id + '_row_' + rowId + '_' + cm.name;

                        result = ' rowspan="1" id="' + cellId + '"'+'"+"';
                        prevCellVal = { cellId: cellId, value: val };
                    }

                    return result ;
                }
```

[image: This is the exact way I want my grid to be like]
[image: The existing scenario]

May be I'm not getting what you are trying to say but this is my current scenario and what I would need to is to move the add new Value dropdown to be added as a new row on the right side under the existing file or files (could be multiple based on the returned value from the server). I have used cellattr function as said above. with the answers i'm not able to fix this. 
Using formatter I'm able to move it to the right side when there are no files are returned. But I'm not able to move it to the side with values returned
Further help would be appreciated 
Thanks in advance

Comment: why not just create your own formatter to suit your needs?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific?
Bcoz there would more than 1 value in Name and Dob columns as well. And i need to add an empty cell every new entry!!
If you could post a sample of the formatter you mentioned it would be extremely helpful

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far?  This way, we can help you with what you need to do.  It's hard to see the way you've configured the grid without any code posted at all.

Comment: I have used the above given cellattr function to combine the cells
sorry for not adding it before

Comment: Look at [the old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12294020/315935). I used `cellattr` to make `rowspan`. So many other jqGrid possibilities could still work. You can try to modify my demo to your purpose. You can try to use `addRowData` and debug the code to find what you can do to make it working.

Answer (score 1):

I posted [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12294020/315935) which shows how one can use `rowspan` attribute to fill the grid which is close to what you do. The demo from the answer you `cellattr`, but one can use `setCell` too to set `rowspan` too.

I made [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/RowSpan3.htm) to demonstrate this. It displays the following grid originally

[image]

after one clicks on the button "Click me to add new row" I use `addRowData` to add the row and use `setCell` to set new values for `rowspan` attributes of some previous rows. So one sees the following picture

[image]

I disable the button "Click me to add new row" because what I wrote is very rough code. I used just fixed values of rowid instead of analyzing the data and evaluating all required values full dynamically. Nevertheless the demo shows clear that one can fill such grids dynamically.

Inside of `click` event handler I used just the following calles

```
$("#list").jqGrid("addRowData", "100", { country: "USA", state: "California",... },
    "last");

$("#list").jqGrid("setCell", "60", "state", "", "", {rowspan: "5"});
$("#list").jqGrid("setCell", "10", "country", "", "", {rowspan: "10"});
```

**UPDATED**: One can add any HTML fragment (like `<button>`) in the same way. [One more demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/RowSpan3_.htm) add buttons in the grid

[image]

Comment: Thanks @oleg But to make my issue a bit more clear as for your example right here my datasource json would come as a server response and I want that button to come inside a cell every time an particular type is over.As for your example after every city in Texas there should be another cell below dallas that says ADD
Same for the state of California as well Anaheim.
So my point is not to add a cell in the end of the grid but at the end of every state

Comment: @MMG: You are welcome! I still don't see any problem. It's better if you explain your problem on **an example** (I mean the test data). I see no difference between local data and the data loaded from the server. You can make all required analyse and sorting of the data either on the server of you can "preprocess" the server response inside of `beforeProcessing` callback. Conditional adding of buttons is very easy if you use custom formatter. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14537512/315935) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13765086/315935).

Comment: I've editted the question with a picture of my required output !!
please have a look 
thanks

Comment: @MMG: I don't see any difference to the previous demo. See new demo from the **UPDATED** part of my answer.

Comment: The data you have mentioned in the demo is hard coded                     *bold**  $("#list").jqGrid("addRowData", "100", { country: "USA", state: "Texas", city: "<button class='mybutton' type='button'>ADD</button>", attraction: "some more", zip: "12345", attr: {country: {display: "none"}, state: {display: "none"}} }, "after", "50"); *bold** 
I was wondering how it would be in terms of dynamic input as if I wouldn't know the values like california or texas or USA, and of course it should be done Onload as well not on a button click  Thanks again in advance

Comment: Sorry for getting back on this so late but now this has become super high priority as I'm done with other issues I had.Looking forward to your help @Oleg

Comment: @MMG: I wrote all data in the demo in so way to show *mostly clear* what can be done. I though that one can understand short code more easy. What you need is *reading of existing data* and *creating* structures (the constants like ids and `rowspan` values) which can be used for `addRowData` and `setCell`. After that you can use the close code.

Comment: I have been trying on this for a while still is not able to figure out. This alone is forcing me to use some other grid despite its other amazing features. Please help me out in this I have added my current scenario.my datasource is of type json. Please help me out in this. Looking forward to your help. Thanks alot @Oleg