# jqGrid : Display one to many relationship in jqGrid MVC 5

Tags: jqgrid, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to display jqGrid in the below format:

Fomat :

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuRYJ.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSEUZ.png)

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Please use correct spelling of jqGrid name. You wrote very short text and you used 3 names: "JQ Grid", "Jqgrid", "JQGrid" instead of jqGrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use `rowspan` to display the data in the format. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12294020/315935). The main problem that such grid can almost **only display** the data. The other functionality starting with sorting by column content, selection of rows, editing and so on can't be used. Is it really what you need? Probably you can better just use the standard `<table>` with `rowspan` attributes? It will be still not so simple to group common input data in the format which you want to display.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Oleg. This is exactly what i wanted. Thanks a lot!