# Is it possible row grouping for newly added row using addRowData in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

Ref Link with data loaded from the server.
http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/RowSpan2.htm

In my scenario. When we add a row using "addRowData" the newly added row should be grouped with the parent row/ with the above row

Comment: I posted the demo for [the following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12294020/315935) old answer. If you use close code you should append the text of your question with the URL to the corresponding demo (in JSFiddle, for example) and the JavaScript code. It's important to know which **version** of jqGrid you use and from which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7).

Comment: In general one need just set `rowspan` or `style="display:none"` attributes on `<td>` elements of new inserted row. You can do that *after* call of `addRowData`. Alternatively the usage of `addRowData` could be slowly, especially in loop if you add multiple rows in the way. The reason if [web browser reflow](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/browser-reflow). Thus replacing local data and reloading the grid could be better as the usage of `addRowData`. In other words you can use your existing code to display the grid and don't use `addRowData` at all.